# AutoCompleteTextView is getting highlighted

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have created a login activity with AutoCompleteTextView components for email and password. Once getting auto completed, these fields are getting highlighted. 
How do I disable this highlighting?
Could not find any relevant property for this one.

[form inputs are getting highlighted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3fmS.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's been a while, I finally found the proper answer. 
This highlight is due to **Android's Autofill Framework.**

To override the highlight setting -

1. SDK min version must be > 26
2. In app theme (style) add the the following item: **android:autofilledHighlight**
   and set the value to whatever color you want (to 'disable' this highlight just set it to transparent).

Comment: Do you know if this is documented somewhere or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I couldn't find any solution via design properties (styles/ layout properties etc.).

I had to use a workaround, which is not the prettiest - but got it done:

1. Added TextChangeListener to relevant EditText:

> mPasswordView.addTextChangedListener(textWatcherWorkAround);

2. Within the Listener, in 'afterTextChanged' overriden method I added:

> ```
> // til is the TextInputLayout wrapping my EditText
> til.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
>
> mPasswordView.removeTextChangedListener(this);
> mEmailView.removeTextChangedListener(this); // To avoid infinite loop
>
> String original = mPasswordView.getText().toString();
> mPasswordView.setText(original + " ");
>
> mPasswordView.addTextChangedListener(this); // To next time
> ```

It ain't pretty, please let me know if you find any, straight-forward, better approach. 
For now - I hope it helps who ever encountered this one!